# Xcode 6 - Undefined symbols for architecture i386 for Parse Framework

Tags: parse-platform, ios8, apple-push-notifications, xcode6

I am trying to create a simple push notification iphone Application  using Parse framework(from Parse.com)  in xcode6. When i compile the app i got Undefined symbols for architecture i386 error. I googled  the error and tried following things:

- Changed target build settings->Build active architectures only to NO
- Tried  changing the standard architectures to : i386 armv7 armv7s (and tried combinations of these)

  Still  i am unable to resolve the error.Below i attached the scrren shots of Target Architectures and linker erros. Any help would be appreciated.[image: Architectures]

[image: Error screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the error. I changed the architectures to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and deleted parse.framework from my project and added parse.framework from working example provided in git:[ParsePlatform PushTutorial](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial)

Here is the screenshot of project and Build Architectures:[image]

Comment: I having with the same problem - not working for me :(